# angularjs: mask the first five digits of SSN

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to mask the first 5 digits of SSN using a filter which should look something like this 
 `XXX-XX-1234`

What I came up with so far:

```
// <td>{{SocialSecurityNumber | ssn}}

angular.module('ng').filter('ssn', function () {
    return function (ssn) {
        if (!ssn) {
            return '';
        }

        var value = ssn.toString().trim().replace(/^\+/, '');

        if (value.match(/[^0-9]/)) {
            return ssn;
        }

        return (ssn.slice(0, 3).replaceWith('*') + '-' + ssn.slice(4, 5).replaceWith('*') + '-' + ssn.slice(4)).trim();
    };
});
```

Comment: if you want to mask them, why would you ever send the full number to client in the first place?

Comment: Yeah, masking in that case is dishonest. It gives the impression the data is not present, giving a false sense of security.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Strings have no `.replaceWith` function in JavaScript.  You can use `.replace`, though.

I'm not sure what `value.match(/[0-9]/)` is supposed to do either.  It seems like you can just remove it.  This will return `true` if the value has even one digit, which it should anyway.  Perhaps you mean `/[^0-9]/`

```
return "XXX-XX-" + ssn.slice(5);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can mask the input box without changing your model value then, this code must help. Here is the working code [Plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/NsTip19zLuBKnpDcTqpg?p=preview) / [Github](https://github.com/deepakkoirala/SSN-Mask-Angular-Js)

```js
var app = angular.module('myapp', []);
app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.modelssn = '';
});

app.directive("ssnInput",function(){
    return {
        require:'ngModel',
        link: function(scop, elem, attr, ngModel){
            $(elem).mask("999-99-9999");
            var temp;
            var regxa = /^(\d{3}-?\d{2}-?\d{4})$/;
            $(elem).focusin(function(){
                $(elem).val(temp);
            });
            $(elem).on('blur',function(){
                temp = $(elem).val();
                if(regxa.test($(elem).val())){
                   $(elem).val("XXX-XX" + temp.slice(6));
               }
            });
        }
    }
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myapp">
  <head>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn.rawgit.com/digitalBush/jquery.maskedinput/master/src/jquery.maskedinput.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.5.x" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.5.11/angular.min.js" data-semver="1.5.11"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    Enter SSN <input type="text" ng-model="modelssn" ssn-input >
    <p>Real SSN {{modelssn}} </p>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
## I faced the similer issue. Below is the solution for that :

angular
.module('app')

.directive('ssnOnly', function () {
           return {
               require: 'ngModel',
               link: function (scope, element, attr, ngModelCtrl) {
                   var flag = 0;
                   function fromUser(text) {
                       if (text) {                          
                           var transformedInput = text.replace(/[^0-9 -]/g, '');                           

                           if (text.length < 3) {
                               flag = 0;
                           } else if (text.length > 3 && text.length < 6) {
                               flag = 1;                              
                           }

                           if (transformedInput !== text) {
                               ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                               ngModelCtrl.$render();
                               alert("Only Numbers Allowed !!!");
                           } else {

                               if (transformedInput.length == 3 && flag == 0) {
                                   transformedInput = transformedInput + '-';
                                   flag = 1;
                               } else if (transformedInput.length == 6 && flag == 1) {
                                   transformedInput = transformedInput + '-';
                                   flag = 2;
                               }

                               if (transformedInput.length == 4 || transformedInput.length == 7)
                               {
                                   var id = transformedInput;
                                   var last = id.substr(id.length - 1);
                                   if (last != '-') {                                      
                                       transformedInput = transformedInput.substring(0, transformedInput.length - 1);
                                       transformedInput = transformedInput + '-' + last;
                                   }                                  
                               }                              

                               ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(transformedInput);
                               ngModelCtrl.$render();                               
                           }
                           return transformedInput;
                       }
                       return undefined;
                   }
                   ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
               }
           };
       })
```

```html
 <input type="text" class="form-control" ssn-only ng-model="ssnNumber" placeholder="SSN" maxlength="11">
```

Comment: Could you elaborate on your answer ?

Comment: @brodoll  The answer creates a directive that can only be placed on an element that has an ngModel directive(any input element).  The rest of the logic is around transforming the input before being rendered (although II'm not quite sure that part is right).